# Create list from Dictionary values, where Dictionary value is a class, and the list I want should have one of the objects of the class

Tags: c#, hbase, thrift

When I read a row from HBase using thrift I get an object of type

```
public class TRowResult : TBase, TAbstractBase {
    public TRowResult.Isset __isset;

    public TRowResult();

    public Dictionary<byte[], TCell> Columns { get; set; }
    public byte[] Row { get; set; }

    public void Read(TProtocol iprot);
    public override string ToString();
    public void Write(TProtocol oprot);

    [Serializable]
    public struct Isset {
      public bool columns;
      public bool row;
    }
}
```

It has a dictionary, where key is the column qualifier and value is

```
public class TCell : TBase, TAbstractBase {
    public TCell.Isset __isset;

    public TCell();

    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    public byte[] Value { get; set; }

    public void Read(TProtocol iprot);
    public override string ToString();
    public void Write(TProtocol oprot);

    [Serializable]
    public struct Isset {
      public bool timestamp;
      public bool value;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a list of byte[] which is present in each TCell. from all the TCell in the dictionary.

Comment: So basically you want `Columns.Values` ?

Comment: No, the value in this case will be TCell, i want a list which contains the byte[], present inside each TCell

Comment: OK, so will `Columns.Values.Select(cell => cell.Value).ToList()` give you what you want?

Comment: I know we can create a list from the values of dictionary using linq. But I dont want to do that

Comment: That's not what the answer does. The answer does exactly what you asked for.  For each value of the dictionary (TCell), it pulls out the Value property of that TCell.

Comment: Also, not directly related to your question, but are you sure you want to be using a struct? Structs are value types and all value types in .NET are immutable. If you change the value of one of the fields of the struct, you are implicitly creating an entire new copy of the struct (not simply changing a single value).

Comment: "But I don't want to do that", I'm sorry but that gives us no idea how to improve the possible answers here. You have to state *what you want*, not what you don't want. Does my second example give you what you want or not, and if not, what do you want instead?

Comment: @dodexahedron I just want the values I wont be changing them anyways.
As I get this data from HBase, its more like reading the data given and using it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple in LINQ:

```
var TCellValues = Columns.Values.Select( c => c.Value );
```

Comment: List<byte[]> allUsers1 = rowData.Columns.Values.Select(c => c.Value).ToList<byte[]>(); This worked..

Comment: It is unnecessary to include the type parameter in the call to ToList().  Also, unless you explicitly need a list or an array, don't call ToList() or ToArray(), because it will cause all objects in the collection to be cloned (copied). Select() returns an IEnumerable, which should be sufficient in most cases.